# How to implement a custom setlength()

Tags: delphi, delphi-6

I want to implement my own MySetLength() function, which might work **exactly** as original SetLength() (from delphi 6) for arrays, **except** I would like to pass **float** parameters as dimensions(then, eventually, round it inside my func, before calling original Setlength()). eg:

```
procedure MySetLength(var A: Array type; Len1: **double**; Len2...);
```

instead of original:

```
procedure SetLength(var A: Array type; Len1: **Integer**; Len2...);
```

where A can have any number of dimensions and can be of any type (strings or floats)

Comment: So, what is your question/problem?

Comment: SetLength is magic, exact reproduction is not possible. While problem is doable, you need to allow some restrictions.

Comment: @danmatei: Are you writing this in Delphi 6, or do you just want it to behave as it did in Delphi 6?  If you are using a later version, you might be able to use Generics and Overloads to handle this. But, if you are actually using Delphi 6, Generics is not an option.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, overloads does not work with `SetLength/Length`. Since they are intrinsic, overloading will hide the intrinsic functions. We were at this with the newly introduced `Low(string)\High(String)` some time ago.

Comment: @LURD: I was suggesting that `MySetLength()` itself can be overloaded, one version for `String` input, one version for array input. `procedure MySetLength(var A: String; Len1: Double); overload; type TWhateverArray = array of Whatever; procedure MySetLength(var A: TWhateverArray; Len1: Double); overload; procedure MySetLength(var A: TWhateverArray; Len1, Len2: Double); overload;`, etc...

Comment: @RemyLebeau, Ok overloading `MySetLength` is doable, no doubt.

Comment: That's not what is being asked for

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: "*I want to implement my own MySetLength() function
 *" - that is exactly what is being **asked for**.  That is not what the OP should **actually implement**, though.  Deltics's solution would be a much better option.

Comment: @remy Asker is looking to write a single function that can accept arbitrary types and numbers of dimension args. Not to write one function for each combination as you do with overloading. Deltics proposes exactly what I proposed in my answer and that is as you say the only sane approach.

Comment: XY Problem ... Why do you want to pass `Double` values to `SetLength`. Floats are fundamentally inappropriate as array sizes, and the fact that you're even considering this means you're doing something horribly wrong. Perhaps explain your ***real*** problem, and get a better solution.

Comment: Yes, i am writing in delphi 6. I need floats because the dimensions come from floating point calculations and i don't want to round them every time I need to call the function.

Comment: What are these calculations? Perhaps it is possible to do them using integer arithmetic?

Answer (score 2):

It's going to be impossible to implement that and make it work exactly as `SetLength` does because `SetLength` is an intrinsic which has compiler and runtime support. This is how the function is able to accept arbitrary array and string types, and accept arbitrary numbers of dimension arguments. Only the compiler vendor can make such a function.

You've really got no hope of producing anything remotely useful that fits the specification in the question. Far and away the best approach is to call `SetLength` directly and apply the `Round` function to any arguments that need to be rounded.

Comment: I already rounded each argument, but I thought there is a simpler solution, since it is tedious and ugly to edit lots of code, adding ROUND() in all the places.  thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you can reduce that impact by encapsulating these arrays so that you don't refer to them directly in application code, only in library code.

Comment: @danmatei - `Round()` uses a particular rounding strategy called "bankers rounding" where .5 rounds to the nearest even number (which could be up **or** down).  Which is why I suggest you implement the specific rounding strategy you determine is appropriate for your array dimensions and apply that in your **SetLength()** calls.  I shall update my answer to make this clear for those who don't already know.

Answer (score 2):

Overloading and Generics come to mind:

```
type
  TMyHelper = class
  public
    class procedure SetLength(var A: String; Len: Double); overload; static;
    class procedure SetLength<T>(var A: TArray<T>; Len: Double); overload; static;
    class procedure SetLength<T>(var A: TArray<TArray<T>>; Len1, Len2: Double); overload; static;
    // as so on...
  end;

class procedure TMyHelper.SetLength(var A: String; Len: Double);
var
  iLen: Integer;
begin
  iLen := ...; // round Len as needed...
  System.SetLength(A, iLen);
end;

class procedure TMyHelper.SetLength<T>(var A: TArray<T>; Len: Double);
var
  iLen: Integer;
begin
  iLen := ...; // round Len as needed...
  System.SetLength(A, iLen);
end;

class procedure TMyHelper.SetLength<T>(var A: TArray<TArray<T>>; Len1, Len2: Double);
var
  iLen1, iLen2: Integer;
begin
  iLen1 := ...; // round Len1 as needed...
  iLen2 := ...; // round Len2 as needed...
  System.SetLength(A, iLen1, iLen2);
end;

// and so on...
```

```
var
  s: string;
  a1: TArray<Integer>;
  a2: TArray<TArray<String>>;
begin
  TMyHelper.SetLength(s, 10);
  TMyHelper.SetLength<Integer>(a1, 10);
  TMyHelper.SetLength<String>(a2, 5, 10);
end;
```

If you are using a version of Delphi that does not support Generics, you can't overload on array element types generically, but you can still overload on arrays if the element types you use is limited, eg:

```
type
  TInteger1DimArray = array of Integer;
  TInteger2DimArray = array of TInteger1DimArray;

  TString1DimArray = array of String;
  TString2DimArray = array of TString1DimArray;

  // and so on...

  TMyHelper = class
  public
    class procedure SetLength(var A: String; Len: Double); overload; static;
    class procedure SetLength(var A: TInteger1DimArray; Len: Double); overload; static;
    class procedure SetLength(var A: TInteger2DimArray; Len1, Len2: Double); overload; static;
    class procedure SetLength(var A: TString1DimArray; Len: Double); overload; static;
    class procedure SetLength(var A: TString2DimArray; Len1, Len2: Double); overload; static;
    // as so on...
  end;

class procedure TMyHelper.SetLength(var A: String; Len: Double);
var
  iLen: Integer;
begin
  iLen := ...; // round Len as needed...
  System.SetLength(A, iLen);
end;

class procedure TMyHelper.SetLength(var A: TInteger1DimArray; Len: Double);
var
  iLen: Integer;
begin
  iLen := ...; // round Len as needed...
  System.SetLength(A, iLen);
end;

class procedure TMyHelper.SetLength(var A: TInteger2DimArray; Len1, Len2: Double);
var
  iLen1, iLen2: Integer;
begin
  iLen1 := ...; // round Len1 as needed...
  iLen2 := ...; // round Len2 as needed...
  System.SetLength(A, iLen1, iLen2);
end;

class procedure TMyHelper.SetLength(var A: TString1DimArray; Len: Double);
var
  iLen: Integer;
begin
  iLen := ...; // round Len as needed...
  System.SetLength(A, iLen);
end;

class procedure TMyHelper.SetLength(var A: TString2DimArray; Len1, Len2: Double);
var
  iLen1, iLen2: Integer;
begin
  iLen1 := ...; // round Len1 as needed...
  iLen2 := ...; // round Len2 as needed...
  System.SetLength(A, iLen1, iLen2);
end;

// and so on...
```

```
var
  s: string;
  a1: TInteger1DimArray;
  a2: TString2DimArray;
begin
  TMyHelper.SetLength(s, 10);
  TMyHelper.SetLength(a1, 10);
  TMyHelper.SetLength(a2, 5, 10);
end;
```

As you can see, implementing `SetLength()` for a single `String` is easy, but implementing `SetLength()` for arrays can get quite complex, depending on the type of arrays you use.  This solution is about as close as you can get in user code without resorting to RTTI so you can call the RTL's `DynArraySetLength()` function directly.

Comment: Thanks, but your solution does not cover an arbitrary number of array dimensions.

Comment: @danmatei not as efficiently as the native `SetLength()`, but additional overloads can be defined for each additional dimension as needed.

Answer (score 2):

Why complicate things trying to work around the problems with overloading or replacing an intrinsic ?

Why not implement the rounding strategy that you would use within your replacement **SetLength** and simply incorporate that into your calls to the intrinsic where appropriate ?

```
SetLength(arr, ArrayDim(dbl));
```

You retain all the capabilities of **SetLength** of course, including the ability to apply your dimension bounds rules for double values to multiple dimensions where necessary:

```
SetLength(multiDimArr, ArrayDim(dblDim1), ArrayDim(dblDim2));
```

Where **ArrayDim** (or named however you see fit) is a function that implements your rounding strategy and returns the corresponding array dimension (**integer**) for the specified input (**double**).

Why would you do this rather than simply using **Round()** ?

The answer is that **Round()** in Delphi uses a particular rounding strategy called *Bankers Rounding*.  This means that **n.5** could round *up **or** down*, depending on the value of **n**.

Even if this rounding strategy is appropriate for your needs currently, you should implement a function to explicitly apply the specific rounding strategy appropriate for array dimensions and use that in your **SetLength()** calls.

Not only does this ensure that you apply the correct rounding strategy in each case, it also means that if you ever need or decide to change your rounding strategy for array dimensions you need only change your *function*, rather than all the calls to **SetLength()** *using* that function.

Comment: What if ARR can have any number of dimensions?

Comment: `SetLength` accepts arrays  of arbitrary dimensions

Comment: `var arr: array of array of ...; ... SetLength(arr, ArrayDim(dbl1), ArrayDim (dbl2), ...);`